# Set variables from an object using reflection doesn't work

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, field

I want to set variables from an object using Reflection.

For simple object this works. (Properties)

But objects with class variables (Fields) doesn’t work. Here I get always an Exeption with "The object does not agree with the target type."

Has anyone here an idea how it could go?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var genericDataSet = new GenericDataSet<DataObjekt>();
        var returnObjekt = genericDataSet.KeepElementsData();
    }
}

public class DataObjekt
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObjektData ModelTyp;
    public DataObjekt() { ModelTyp = new ObjektData(); }
}

public class ObjektData
{
    public string Typ { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class GenericDataSet<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public T KeepElementsData()
    {
        var item = new T();
        //Propertys durchlaufen
        foreach (var Property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            item.GetType().GetProperty(Property.Name).SetValue(item, "TestData");  //this works
        }

        //Fields durchlaufen
        foreach (var Field in item.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            foreach (var FieldProperty in item.GetType().GetField(Field.Name).FieldType.GetProperties())
            {
                var data = item.GetType().GetField(Field.Name).FieldType.GetProperty(FieldProperty.Name);
                data.SetValue(item, "TestData not work", null); // this doesent work
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `item.GetType().GetField(Field.Name)` rather than just using `Field`? (I'd also urge you to start following .NET naming conventions - your local variables would normally be `field` and `fieldProperty`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are setting the value on the wrong object:

```
data.SetValue(item, "TestData not work", null);
```

`item` doesn't have this property, its the field that has it.
You need to create an instance of that field (if its null), then fill its properties and then set it to the field.

The following will work for you:

```
public class GenericDataSet<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public T KeepElementsData()
    {
        var item = new T();
        //Propertys durchlaufen
        foreach (var propertyInfo in item.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).SetValue(item, "TestData");  //this works
        }

        //Fields durchlaufen
        foreach (var fieldInfo in item.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            object fieldObject = Activator.CreateInstance(fieldInfo.FieldType);

            // Or if it's already instantiated: 
            // object fieldObject = fieldInfo.GetValue(item);

            foreach (var fieldProperty in fieldInfo.FieldType.GetProperties())
            {
                fieldProperty.SetValue(fieldObject, "TestData not work", null); // this doesent work
            }
            fieldInfo.SetValue(item, fieldObject);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to do :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see this shouldn´t even work for properties, as you provide only string-data, while not all of your properties have string-type. Anyway in your fields-loop why do you have a nested loop at all? You´re looping the properties of every fields *type*, which is quite bpring I guess. So if your field has type string you iterate in the inner loop all the fields from `String`. You should be able to omit the inner loop and write the same what you´re doing for properties. Furthermore you can directly set the properties value for the current `item`.

```
var item = new T();
//Propertys durchlaufen
foreach (var property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    property.SetValue(item, "TestData");  //this works
}

//Fields durchlaufen
foreach (var field in item.GetType().GetFields())
{
    field.SetValue(item, "TestData");
}
```

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel Why? I allready mentioned that the fields are not all strings, so Of course it won´t work for all, but at least for the very first which is what OP actually asks.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, there are not only Property's with string's, but for this I have an solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public T KeepElementsData()
{
    var item = new T();
    //Propertys durchlaufen
    foreach (var property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        property.SetValue(item, "TestData");  //this works
    }

    //Fields durchlaufen
    foreach (var field in item.GetType().GetFields())
    {
        var value = field.GetValue(item);
        var type = value.GetType();

        foreach (var fieldProperty in type.GetProperties())
        {
            fieldProperty.SetValue(value, "TestData works");
        }
    }
    return item;
}
```

You are going back and forth between the PropertyInfo->name of the PropertyInfo->PropertyInfo... plus you are mixing the `item` object with its fields...